# html5 site suddenly fails validation

Tags: validation, html

html5, built in wordpress

http:///www.thejumperweb.co.uk

is suddenly failing W3c htl5 validation, it was passing last week and nothing has changed.

its failing on
Bad value profile for attribute rel on element link: Keyword profile is not registered.

Any clues much appreciated or is perhaps the actual validator not playing ball.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the [error results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.thejumperweb.co.uk#result) say, the two values for `rel` it's complaining about, "*home*" and "*profile*", aren't [in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#linkTypes).

- [`rel="home"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-home) is in draft at this stage
- [`rel="profile"`](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-profile) was drafted for XHTML 2 and it's done a bit differently [in HTML 5](http://microformats.org/wiki/html5-profile).

Comment: ah, the rel=profile was created by wordpress, so thats a bit of a nightmare then, also my lightbox gallery uses rel to determine the gallery, so i guess thats going to cause problems.
Also, im guessing this has just been added then because exactly the same code was validating last week,